# Installed Sp2013 without using a service account

Tags: 2013

I have installed SP2013 using my domain account and now when I login it says my account is a 'System Account'

I have now read that I needed to install SP2013 with specific accounts like SPfarm, SPAdmin etc

DO I need to reinstall SP2013 again?

Thanks

Comment: No, no need to reinstall again. In your case 'System Account' is farm admin.

Comment: Ok so how do I change it so my account is no longer the farm admin, thanks

Comment: You have to add an another account, create it from active directory, and assign all database permission. Include that user in farm administrator group and  in farm administrator group in central admin.

Comment: I would recommend to take a look at this article from Microsoft, about administrative and service accounts in SharePoint. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445(v=office.15).aspx